# Deploy (git pull latest commits) from Acquia Cloud Staging repo to LIVE site on shared hosting environment

Tags: git, shared-hosting, acquia

I want to develop three small websites locally (Acquia Dev Desktop) and push changes to Acquia Cloud (dev / staging), to show my client the process etc.

Is it possible to `git pull` (deploy) all latest commits (changes) from Acquia Cloud *staging repo* to a remote server (shared hosting environment), to deploy those changes to the LIVE website (on shared hosting environment)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to git pull (deploy) all latest commits (changes) from Acquia Cloud staging repo to a remote server (shared hosting environment), to deploy those changes to the LIVE website (on shared hosting environment)?

Yes.

## ***`Multiple remotes`***

```
git remote add remote1 <url1>
git remote add remote1 <url2>
...
git remote add remoten <url1>
```

Once you have all the remotes set up, you can `pull/push` from any of your remotes to any desired branch (on same origin of on different one).

---

## ***`Submodules`***

Another thing you can do it to use `submodules` inside a bigger repo.
You will have to set up a parent repository and then add each repo as submodule and use it.

[image]